# Is the pointwise limit of $f_\nu$ with $\sup_\nu \|f_\nu\|_{L^1}<C$ sequence still in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a Lebesgue measure space. Assume that $f_{\nu}\in L^1(X,\mu)$ and $f_{\nu}\to f$ everywhere and
$\|f_{\nu}\|_{L^1}\leq C$, where $C>0$ is a constant.

Does this imply that $f\in L^1(X,\mu)$ and $\|f\|_{L^1}\leq C$?

If not, assume that $\|f_{\nu}\|_{L^1}$ is increasing with $\nu$, can we get the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true and it follows immediately from Fatou's Lemma: $\int |f| \leq \lim \inf \int|f_n| \leq C$.